# How to write a cloud function for firebase that will change data based on time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database structure looks like this:

```
-events
    -uniqueEventId
        -endTimeStamp: 1507949100
        -active: true
    -uniqueEventId2
        -endTimeStamp: 1807949100
        -active: true
    -uniqueEventId3
        -endTimeStamp: 1900949100
        -active: true
```

How do I cloud function which can get all the events with timestamps before the current time and set their active to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want Cloud Functions to be triggered in this case. I'll assume you want a HTTP trigger, so that you can simply call it from the browser or a web hook.

That means you start with a basic [HTTP-triggered function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events):

```
exports.updateStatus = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
  res.status(200).send("done");
});
```

Next up you'll need to access the Realtime Database within this function. To do that you'll use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin), which gives you easy administrative access within your code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateStatus = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
  res.status(200).send("done");
});
```

Then we get to the actual code to change the data. This is standard database access code and has little to do with Cloud Functions. In this case you want to query for timestamp, loop over the results, and set the `active` property:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.updateStatus = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  let now = Date.now();
  let query = admin.database().ref("events").orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(now);
  query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var promises = [];
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      promises.push(child.ref.update({ active: false }));
    })
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      res.status(200).send("done");
    });
  });
});
```

That last code is a bit tricky, since it deals with many asynchronous write operations. Cloud Functions will terminate your function after your send the response to the client, so it's important that you only send a response back after all those asynchronous writes are done. I use a `Promise.all()` for that. For more information on this asynchronous nature, read [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html), and watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc).

For more info, I'd recommend studying the [documentation for the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).